# Render PartialView from background thread using SqlDependency

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-mvc-4, sqldependency

I'm trying to update a PartialView when a register is updated in DataBase. I'm using SqlDependency and the event rise properly when the change happens.

```
SqlDependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(sqlDependency_OnChange);
```

Method:

```
Private void sqlDependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Ok");

        UpdateView();

    }
```

And the method that is called:

```
 public ActionResult UpdateView()
    {
        try
        {
            //Blablabla...
            //Business logic...
            //Blablabla...
            model = 2;

            return PartialView(model);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return PartialView(0);
        }
    }
```

I receive every time a change is made the Lines in the OutputWindow, the method UpdateView() exits with no errors, but the PartialView is not render any more.

The View:

```
@model int
<h4>You have @Model points.</h4>
```

What I'm doing wrong?
Is it because I'm requesting the Render from a different thread? 
Can I Update a View from server side when an event occurs?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Web requests typically fall into a simple pattern that looks like this: request > process (this is your asp.net code) > send response to client. Once the output is sent to the client, it's End of Story. Now, what happens if a db record is updated AFTER the client request/response is complete? How do you plan to send that updated view back to the client? Think about this issues and try to understand the basics behind how http/web pages/asp.net/php or whatever else delivers html to clients before you worry about multi-threading.

Comment: I'm quite sure that the problem is that the `ActionResult` returned from `UpdateView()` doesn't go anywhere: you just ignore it. (I don't know enough about MVC to help you fix that, if that's even possible.)

Comment: or take the shortcut and check SignalR [link](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/sending-notifications-using-asp.net-signalr.htm)

Comment: @svick , thanks for your answer and edit. I agree that I'm ignoring it, but how could I manage it if the output has been already sent to the client?

Comment: @bkdc , thanks for your answer and link. I understand what you say. Because of that, how could I manage data from a background thread if data has been already sent to the client? If it's not possible, what sense have multithreading in web environment?

Comment: multithreading & web: ask your PHP friends :) Jokes aside, there can be many uses for it: SignalR is just one example. Being able to run things in the background instead of only when there's a request from a client can give you a lot of freedom to do interesting (and useful) stuff. The "problem", in your case, is sending back to the client that interesting stuff you've done in the background; there are multiple approaches to solving this issue: have your client poll for changes using Ajax, SignalR (again) or simply have the background task update whatever is needed for the next client request